# Rails 3.1 on Heroku Bamboo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Can someone point out to some nice guide for deploying a Rails 3.1 on Heroku Bamboo stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn off the asset pipeline for your Rails 3.1 app and it should work.

Comment: Is there a way to tell rails 3.1 to pre-package the assets before deployment?

Comment: `rake assets:precompile` will put your assets in the public directory.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually found the entry in rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Answer (score -1):

If you use capistrano add load `deploy/assets` to your `Capfile`